# Injecting properties into Spring Rest Controller via XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, applicationcontext

Right now I have a Spring based RESTful web-app. I'm very new to REST and so I followed some tutorials online. I built my web.xml, my rest-servlet.xml that uses the component-scan tag and loads up my RestController class which uses the @RestController annotation. (All of the code is posted below)

My issue is that none of these tutorials show me how to inject beans into my controller via an ApplicationContext.xml. I've found ways to inject using annotations, but I really want to use xml configuration. In my example below I have three database clients that I want to be wired in with the RestController when it starts up.

Any suggestions on how to load the ApplicationContext.xml on startup so that my RestController servlet receives the correct instances of the database clients?

web.xml

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworld.example" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
  </beans>
```

RestController.java

```
package com.helloworld.example;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class SpringServiceController {

@Autowired
DBClient1 dbClient1;

@Autowired
DBClient2 dbClient2;

@Autowired
DBClient3 dbClient3;


 @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getGreeting(@PathVariable String name) {
  String result="Hello "+name + " " dbClient1.toString(); // this is a test to see if the wiring worked  
  return result;
 }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dbClient1" class="com.helloworld.example.DBClient1"/>

    <bean id="dbClient2" class="com.helloworld.example.DBClient2"/>

    <bean id="dbClient3" class="com.helloworld.example.DBClient3"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register a `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml` which loads your `applicationContext.xml`. The process is described in the documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet).

Your `@Controller` bean will be loaded by your `DispatcherServlet` which will use the beans in the `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: It's not really well described there. Do I add the <context-param> tag in and add my applicationContext.xml as the contextConfigLocation?

Comment: @the_camino You have to add a `<listener>` entry for the `ContextLoaderListener` and then add the `<context-param>` with the location of your XML file.

Comment: That's what I thought, I did this and now I'm running into FileNotFoundExceptions... trying to sort that out. Not sure what directory spring starts with

Comment: @the_camino Where is your applicationContext.xml file located relative to the root of your WAR?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your web.xml should be
Note that your rest-servlet.xml must be in the same folder with web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to load my applicationContext.xml my rest-servlet.xml works just fine